# What's the proper way to add an index to a table in a Rails migration?

Tags: postgresql, reference, migration, unique, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 with PostGres 9.5 . I have the following migration

```
class CreateCryptoIndexCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :crypto_index_currencies do |t|
      t.references :crypto_currency, foreign_key: true
      t.date :join_date, :null => false, :default => Time.now
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :crypto_index_currencies, :crypto_currency, unique: true
  end
end
```

Upon running the migration, it is dying with this error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "crypto_currency" does not exist
```

What is the proper way to add the index?  The table name that I want to reference is called "crypto_currencies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 add_index 'crypto_index_currencies', ['crypto_currency'], name: "index_crypto_index_currencies_on_crypto_currency", unique: true, using: :btree
```

**using: :btree** its optional.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax to add it inside the create_table block

```
class CreateCryptoIndexCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :crypto_index_currencies do |t|
      t.references :crypto_currency, foreign_key: true
      t.date :join_date, :null => false, :default => Time.now
      t.index :crypto_currency, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```